# Mongoose get all elements in array of multiple documents

Tags: mongoose

I have a Schema Classroom with properties:
  _id
  studentEmails (array of Strings. Each student has an unique email)

I am given an array of Classroom ids, and I want to find every student email that belongs one of those classrooms, **without duplicates**. How do I do this? I was thinking I could get every student email and then remove duplicates later, but I would much rather do it through mongoose.

For example, if I had the following classrooms:

```
_id: 1
studentEmails: ["a@school.edu", "b@school.edu"]

_id: 2
studentEmails: ["b@school.edu", "d@school.edu"]
```

And the following query parameter:

```
[1, 2]
```

I want to get [a@school.edu, b@school.edu, d@school.edu]. The _id is a mongoose ObjectId, but simplified in the example.

Comment: you can use in, here is sample      p.find()
            
            .where("studentEmails")
            .in([1, 2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `distinct` method with condition for this.

```js
Model.distinct(
  "studentEmails",
  { _id: { $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId("1"), mongoose.Types.ObjectId("2")] } },
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
);
```